# Image Asset Loading Well on the Web But not on Mobile

Tags: flutter

I have an issue with my Flutter application. I am trying to load a simple image on my SplashWidget as below.

When I do `flutter run -d chrome` the image loads perfectly fine on the Web (Google Chrome).

Now when I test against my real Android Device(Huawei EVA LO9) running on Marshmallow (Android 6.0) I am getting the below error:

```
                    ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
                    The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
                    Unable to load asset: images/splash_icon.png
                    
                    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
                    #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:227:7)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
(package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:667:14)
                    <asynchronous suspension>
                    ...
                    
                    Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/splash_icon.png")
                    Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#d1d58(), name:
                      "images/splash_icon.png", scale: 1.0)
```

Here is my SplashWiget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class SplashWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: BrandColors.PRIMARY_COLOR),
      child: Center(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage("images/splash_icon.png"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Here is a screenshot of my directory structure

[image]

Do I need to do any android specific configurations to get this image to load on a real android device. I can't believe I have wasted hours on a simple thing like this. This is exhausting.

Someone please help me.

Comment: Try using `Image.asset("assets/images/splash_icon.png")`

Comment: @sajithlakmal I have tried that and it didn't work as well.

Comment: Then try changing src as `assets/images/splash_icon.png`

Comment: Have you found any solutions yet?

Comment: Flutter by default does not index subfolders.
You have to include every folder with assets:

`- assets/animations/`


`- assets/iamges/`


`- assets/fonts/`

Subfolder indexing works only for resolution aware resources: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images#resolution-aware

Answer (score 0):

try do something like this:

```
  Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("images/splash_icon.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  )
```

First you see if this is running fine, and after apply your logic / style.

Tell me if this doesn't work.

Also try make an - **flutter clean**. Then - **flutter run**
;)

Answer (score 0):

for me what i found that the path need to be in code fully same as in pubspec.yaml

so in your pubspec.yaml like this :

```
assets:
- assets/images/
```

and in your code where you want to load the image like this :

```
image: AssetImage('assets/images/image1.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75303056/1388723) above by [JOH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10261197/joh) is correct.

Though I would like to bring the source of the need to define subfolders in `assets` section of the `pubspec.yml`

In official [documentations](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images) we can see info block:

[image]

Every assets subfolder needs to land in `pubspec.yml`

So for your case please define the following:

```
assets:
- assets/images/
- assets/fonts/
- assets/animations/
```

Additionaly, take a look at the documentation for Asset Variants where subfolder scanning happens.